# ggplot2 geom_bar: plot sum of two variables and group by proportion of each variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

I could not find an answer / a solution to the following question:

I have two numeric variables. I take the sum of both and want to bar plot the relative frequency of that summed variable + indicate the proportion of its sub components (i.e. the mean proportion of one variable as part of the sum).

Example: I have v1 = number questions and v2 = number of answers. Each observation can have x questions and y answers and x+y interactions.

Example code:

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 2, nrow = 5))
x <- c("questions", "answers")
colnames(df) <- x

df$questions <- c(1,2,3,1,2)
df$answers <- c(2,3,4,2,3)
df$interactionsum <- df$questions + df$answers


ggplot(df, aes(x = interactionsum)) +
  geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..))) + 
  ylab("Relative frequencies") +
  xlab("Sum of interactions")
```

In this data setting, one third of the first bar would be questions (mean proportion) and two thirds answers (mean proportion). How can I achieve this type of grouping with ggplot2?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: But the proportion of each variable can vary within a sum. Do you want the mean proportion?

Comment: Yes I know, and yes! :-) Best would be to put an error bar for each mean proportion, but not thaat necessary

Comment: How do you want to plot sum of interactions on the x-axis and relative frequencies on the y-axis in a bar chart?

Comment: You mentioned "one third of the first bar". How many bars do you expect? It should be only one bar if you want the "mean proportion".

Comment: @franziskalypse he's treating the sum as a factor.

Comment: e.g. the first bar has 3 interactions. For the cases where there are 3 interactions, 1/3 is the proportion that are questions

Comment: Not clear to me if you'll always have the same rows for the same `interactionsum` or not. You can use distinct rows of your dataset, or calculate the proportions for each `interactionsum`. I've posted a solution that assumes the 2nd case.

Comment: Thank you! I couln't manage to fit your solution to my needs because summarise_all integrates the result of the added n() command. What I need is your solution, but the height of the bars should not be lost. I.e. initially the height for 3 was 0.4. the proportion of questions here should be 1/3 of 0.4

Comment: Note that I revised my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 2, nrow = 5))
x <- c("questions", "answers")
colnames(df) <- x

df$questions <- c(1,2,3,1,2)
df$answers <- c(2,3,4,2,3)
df$interactionsum <- df$questions + df$answers

require(dplyr) 
require(tidyr)
require(ggplot2) 
df<-df  %>% group_by(interactionsum) %>% 
  summarize(questions=mean(questions)/mean(interactionsum) ,answers=mean(answers)/mean(interactionsum) , n=n()/nrow(df) ) %>% mutate(interactionsum=as.factor(interactionsum)) %>% 
  gather("key","means",questions, answers) 
ggplot(df,aes(x=interactionsum,y=means*n,fill=key))+geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

For each possible interaction sum, we create the mean of all its questions variable and the mean of all its answer variable. Then we gather then (using `tidyr`) to make the long data format favoured by ggplot, then we plot those means in a stacked bar using the "identity" statistic, since they already reflect the frequency in the value.

I also turned interaction sum into a factor to improve the way it looks in the end result.

[image]

Comment: Now showing the relative frequency rather than number of cases.

Answer (score 1):

```
# example data
df = data.frame(questions = c(1,2,3,1,2),
                answers = c(2,3,4,2,3))

df$interactionsum <- df$questions + df$answers

library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(interactionsum) %>%
  summarise_all(sum) %>%
  gather(x,y,-interactionsum) %>%
  group_by(interactionsum) %>%
  mutate(y = y/sum(y)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(interactionsum, y, fill=x))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

[image]